# Wrong Date output when inserting timestamp in Date Object (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, date, object, fetch-api

I am trying to use data from the https://www.cryptocompare.com/ api. Weard thing is, when I  want to create a new Date Object with that timestamp, I get Tue Jan 20 1970 07:09:15 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit) back. The timestamp is right tho, i checked that on https://timestampgenerator.com/date-from-timestamp.

```
requestLatestNews();
    function requestLatestNews() {
        fetch(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=EN&api_key=<key>`)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            })
            .then((data) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++) {
                    let publishDate = new Date(data.Data[i].published_on); // Falsche Berechnung
                    console.log(publishDate);
                    let dmy = publishDate.getUTCDate() + "/" + (publishDate.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "/" + publishDate.getUTCFullYear();
                    let hms = publishDate.getUTCHours() + ":" + publishDate.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + publishDate.getUTCSeconds();
                    document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML
                        += `<p> <a href="${data.Data[i].guid}">${data.Data[i].source}</a> - ${data.Data[i].title}, ${dmy} ${hms}</p>
                    <img src="${data.Data[i].imageurl}"></img> <p> [${data.Data[i].tags} ${data.Data[i].categories}] </p>
                    <p> ${data.Data[i].body} </p>`;
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error Code: ' + error);
            });
    }
```

Comment: (linux) timestamps are in seconds - javascript stores Dates as milliseconds since an epoch ... multiply by 1000

Comment: "*Weard thing is, when I want to create a new Date Object with that timestamp*" with *what* timestamp? Please include all the information related to the question *in* the question.

Comment: @VLAZ one of the current timestamps is 1663756264. The api offers the 50 newest news by default, so that timestamps change by time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should take a look at the Date contructor for JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Quoting from the documentation:

#### Time value or timestamp number - value

> An integer value representing the number of milliseconds since January
> 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC (the ECMAScript epoch, equivalent to the UNIX
> epoch), with leap seconds ignored. Keep in mind that most UNIX
> Timestamp functions are only accurate to the nearest second.

You can try out the value you receive on that page as well.